# What instance of Spock betraying Kirk is Marty referring to?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

In the movie *Daddy Day Care* I recall the character Marty saying at one point:

> This is worse than the time Spock betrayed Kirk

Now, I know *Daddy Day Care* isn't sci-fi, but it got me to thinking, I don't *ever* recall a time when Spock actually betrayed Kirk.  So, assuming that Marty actually is the massive Star Trek fan he is, **what particular circumstance of Spock betraying Kirk is Marty referring to?**

Comment: TOS: The Menagerie could also be counted as a betrayal, since Spock steals the Enterprise from Kirk.

Comment: @Ixrec yes I had thought of that and tbh that's probably just as valid as his betrayal in Star Trek V actually

Comment: There's a bunch of times when Spock disregards orders, what about when he gets hit with the spores? What about when he steals the ship in menagerie? What about when he strikes kirk in the pon farr? Etc. Etc. It depends on how you define betrayal, kind of a broad question. I don't think any of those things rise to the level of betrayal, but they're definitely disobeying orders. This might be a bit broad if you don't define what you mean by betrayal.

Comment: @JMFB you make a valid point; I'll work on confining it a bit more

Comment: @N_Soong BLASPHEMY! It'd never happen. The question is much better now. I've seen everything Star Trek except The Animated Series which is debatable if it's canon. So...I can tell you with authority there's never a time where a sane Spock in control of his faculties tried to purposely betray Kirk to hurt Kirk in the process. Do you want me to write this as an answer?

Comment: @JMFB I see I've opened up a can of worms with this; there's far more instances than I initially thought.  Perhaps I'll confine it to what instance was *Marty* referring to.  Feel free to ask the broader question of how many times did Spock betray Kirk though!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## In Star Trek V

The exact quote from [*Daddy Day Care*](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/d/daddy-care-care-script-transcript.html) is:

> This is worse than when Spock betrayed Kirk on "Star Trek V".

Now, the scene which Marty must be referring to is described on [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_V:_The_Final_Frontier) (emphasis mine) as:

> Kirk scuffles briefly with Sybok, during which Sybok's weapon falls
>   away near Spock's feet. He grabs the weapon and has Sybok at gunpoint.
>   To Kirk's surprise, however, **Spock refuses to shoot him, and they are
>   taken hostage and thrown with McCoy into a holding cell. Kirk is
>   furious and blasts Spock for betraying the entire ship and crew.**

Without spoiling the rest of the movie though, bear in mind that this betrayal is only temporary!

Comment: It's not betrayal to not want to kill your own brother. You defined betrayal as "...knowingly act in a way which caused Kirk harm when it was not ordered by Kirk." What harm did this cause Kirk? There was no intention of harm by this act nor was there harm done. Inaction is hardly betrayal in this case.

Comment: Arguably, Spock's decision to commit The Enterprise to the diplomatic mission with Qo'noS One was also a betrayal.

Comment: @Politank-Z how was that betrayal? He wasn't trying to hurt Kirk and he knew that Kirk was the only one who could pull it off.

Comment: I fail to understand the reason for the downvote; the answer completely addresses the question which is specifically inquiring about what Marty was referring to.

Comment: @JMFB Spock arranged the assignment without consulting Kirk. Spock was well aware of Kirk's history with the Klingons, and was aware that, if asked, Kirk may have refused the assignment. If Kirk was the only one who could pull it off, it betrayed a lack of faith on Spock's part not to give Kirk the opportunity to refuse. It was a betrayal of their friendship.

Comment: I've download both the Q and A, however reluctantly. First, you posted the A at the same time or a few mins after the Q. It's fine to answer your own Q I think, but it looks like you knew the A already...so what was the point of this exercise?

Comment: Also, how does this help us understand the SF work, which is Star Trek in this case? It doesn't. It only helps us to understand Daddy Day Care.

Comment: I meant downvoted, obviously.

Comment: @T-5000 : N_Soong's question was inspired by *Daddy Day Care*, but the answer *does* help us to understand *Star Trek* better.  It helps us to understand Kirk and Spock's relationship, which is a key friendship within 20th Century science fiction.  One might be surprised to believe that Spock has betrayed Kirk.  JMFB's reaction to the question proves this. The question and its answer help us to see an aspect of *Star Trek* that gets glossed over by our tendency to view a well-studied fictional body through the tropes it has created.  This is why I had upvoted both the question and the answer.

Comment: @T-5000 I assure you that I performed the research *following* the question; I did not know the answer in advance.  In any event, this site ***does*** offer the facility to 'offer your knowledge Q&A style', so even if I did know the answer already, it is still perfectly fine by this site

Comment: No, I don't accept it. ST:V never existed. It never happened. For some strange reason, the movies skipped V and went straight from IV to VI.

Comment: I'll also "download" this question -1.  Once you knew the exact quote, the question is answered outright.

Comment: The quote from Memory Alpha is misleading.  Kirk did not blast Spock with a phaser or other energy weapon or blast him with dynamite or any other explosive.  All Kirk did was verbally express dissatisfaction with Spock's behavior.

Comment: The quote from Memory Alpha is misleading.  Kirk did not blast Spock with a phaser or other energy weapon or blast him with dynamite or any other explosive.  All Kirk did was verbally express dissatisfaction with Spock's behavior.